# Using the integral test

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, continuity

I want to show that  $$A_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^2+n}$$ for $n\in$$\mathbb{N}$ and $N\in$$\mathbb{N}$ is convergent. I think I can use the integral test to show that.  I got that $$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2+x}dx=\ln(2)$$. But how can I 
formally show that $\frac{1}{x^2+x}$ is continuous and decreasing which is one of the conditions for using the test?

Answer (score 1):

Using the forward difference notation $\Delta f(n)=f(n+1)-f(n)$ $$A_N=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n^2+n}$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^N \Delta (-\frac{1}{n})$$
$$=-\sum_{n=1}^N \Delta (\frac{1}{n})$$
$$=-(\frac{1}{n}|_1^{N+1})$$
$$=1-\frac{1}{N+1}.$$
You can take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

The map $x\mapsto x^2+x$ ($x\in[1,\infty)$) is continuous since it's the sum of two continuous maps. And it is increasing since it is the sum of two increasing maps. Therefore, $x\mapsto\frac1{x^2+x}$ is continuous and decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

Polynomials are continuous, and happy quadratics increase to the right of their minimum, so $x^2+x$ increases when $x>-\frac12$, and is positive for $x>0$. Now take the reciprocal.

Answer (score 0):

Decreasing:

Let $x<y$, $x,y >0;$

$f(y)-f(x)=$

$\frac{1}{y^2+y} -\frac{1}{x^2+x} = \frac{x^2+x-y^2-y}{(y^2+y)(x^2+x)}=$

$\frac{(x-y)(x+y)+(x-y)}{(y^2+y)(x^2+x)}=\frac{(x-y)(x+y+1)}{(y^2+y)(x^2+x)}<0.$

Answer (score 0):

$A_N=\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\dfrac 1{n^2+n}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\left(\dfrac 1n-\dfrac 1{n+1}\right)=1-\dfrac 1{N+1}\to 1$

$A_N$ is a series with positive terms and $n^2+n>n^2\implies A_N\le\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\dfrac 1{n^2}<\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac 1{n^2}<+\infty$